# How to get 'è' (and not 'e') with activerecord and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, activerecord, utf-8

I am writing a simple script to update a table data. 
I am unable to get a record trough a field named "Agliè"; the problem is "è".

```
c = Comune.find_by_denominazione_italiano_tedesco('Agliè')
```

I realised that the problem can be patched using "Aglie", but I need to preserve the accent difference (these are town names, some are the same, except of the accent).

My db character set is UTF-8, the collation is latin1_swedish_ci; however, changing it to utf8_general_ci makes no difference. My ruby script is in utf-8; I tried changing it to latin1 as well, no difference again.

Any suggestion?

Cheers,

Davide

Comment: When you say you can't get it through, do you mean that the update results in error, or it silently converts to `e`? Or does it get saved in the database, but gets lost/changed when you try retrieve it? What kind of database (SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle,...)?

Comment: I get a 'nil' object. However, curiously, the actual query generated by activerecord seems correct (and works through phpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a file encoding problem after all, grr.
Thanks anyway folks.